# Ubuntu Gnome or Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome

I am probably missing something fundamental here but what is the difference between installing Ubuntu Gnome and installing plain Ubuntu and then installing Gnome Shell from the repositories? Apart, of course, that one also gets Unity.

Is there a best option for getting a pure Gnome experience?

Andrew

Comment: Nattgew's answer is correct, but to add on one point; you're correct. Other than having Unity, the systems should pretty much be the same. There are two meta packages (ubuntu-desktop and gnome-desktop-environment). If you took a standard Ubuntu desktop and installed the gnome-desktop-environment package, you would get the same end-result as installing ubuntu-desktop on an Ubuntu Gnome install. They both use packages from the same sources.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure Gnome experience, then Ubuntu Gnome is better.

If you install Gnome Shell with regular Ubuntu, you will just have a choice between Unity and Gnome. You will end up with some Unity packages you don't really need. You will also end up with both GDM and LightDM. This shouldn't be an issue, but less complexity means less can go wrong later on.